# Give/get arguments in popup from "on_press"

Tags: python, arguments, kivy, popen

Pardon me for my simple question, but I don't understand some thing.
I want to give a few arguments from button which is located in popup window in one method to another method.

Example:

.py code

```
class GeneralForm(TabbedPanel):

    def EDIT(self,D):
        box1=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        t1=TextInput(text=GeneralForm.PARSE(self,D)) 
        b2=Button(text='Save')
        b3=Button(text='Cancel')


        box2=BoxLayout()

        box2.add_widget(b2)
        box2.add_widget(b3)

        box1.add_widget(t1)
        box1.add_widget(box2)

        popup = Popup(content=box1,auto_dismiss=False,size_hint=(.75,.75),title='Edit')
        b2.bind(on_press=self.SAVE_EDIT) <====== There is a problem
        b3.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss) 
        popup.open()


    def SAVE_EDIT(self,instance):
       !!! DOING SOMETHING !!!
```

https://s3.amazonaws.com/xasan/snapshot/stack1.png

What I want:

In method "EDIT" I have text input "t1". After changing text in this text input I press button "b2" which calls method SAVE_EDIT with two arguments.

So, I want to give the third agrument to "SAVE_EDIT" method which will return an edited text in t1.

Something like this:

.py code

```
class GeneralForm(TabbedPanel):

def EDIT(self,D):
    box1=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    t1=TextInput(text=GeneralForm.PARSE(self,D))
    b2=Button(text='Save')
    b3=Button(text='Cancel')


    box2=BoxLayout()

    box2.add_widget(b2)
    box2.add_widget(b3)

    box1.add_widget(t1)
    box1.add_widget(box2)

    popup = Popup(content=box1,auto_dismiss=False,size_hint=(.75,.75),title='Edit')
    b2.bind(on_press=self.SAVE_EDIT(t1.txt)) <====== There is a problem
    b3.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss) 
    popup.open()


def SAVE_EDIT(self,instance,TEXT): <====== There is a problem
   !!! DOING SOMETHING with TEXT!!!
```

Step-by-step:

> 1. Popen window was opened with some text in the text input.
> 2. We edited  text, deleted something or added.
> 3. We are clicking  on button "Save"(b2) and all text in txt input(t1) push to method "SAVE_EDIT" where we save,parse or do something else
>      with this text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `lambda`:

```
on_press=lambda instance, text=t1.txt: self.SAVE_EDIT(instance, TEXT=text)
```

Or [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
on_press=partial(self.SAVE_EDIT, TEXT=t1.txt)
```

Both variants use `t1.txt` at the time of the `bind` call i.e., the value may be obsolete by the time you press the button.

To use the current most recent value:

```
on_press=lambda instance: self.SAVE_EDIT(instance, TEXT=t1.txt)
```

In this case, `t1.txt` is called each time the callback is invoked.

Comment: But I have a new problem :) All the text which I'm editing, isn't pushing to  SAVE_EDIT method. Only old text which was in t1=TextInput(text=GeneralForm.PARSE(self,D)) before clicking the button Save is going to SAVE_EDIT.  Why text=t1.text get old value of variable? Once again I apologize)

Comment: @AntonyMakaruk: I've updated the answer to show how to use the most recent `t1.txt` value

Comment: Now I undestand. Thank you so much.